What happend with tags?
Is it new tag design?



The whole style of tags is changed: font, colors, filling ...
That's how it looked before, e.g. on ruSO.meta



And now it looks like that:



I didn't find any new related annoncements.

I thought I had messed up a browser setting. Where was this announced indeed or is this yet another middle finger to the moderator agreement deal from last summer?

@nitsua60 not only font but the entire style: font, colors, filling ...

Sorry for beating you at reporting this, here's an upvote ;) BTW, the greatest deficiency of this post past its timing seems to be the lack of badly hand-drawn  red circles around the offending parts of the screenshots ;)

@DanMašek you were 44 seconds faster. You deserve it :)
